# Dual Boot - Making grub.cfg changes permanent through 40_custom

Tags: grub2, windows

I am dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu on the same hard drive and when i select Windows 10 from the grub menu at startup it just shows a black screen and after 1-2 seconds it returns to grub. I found a solution which is to add `ntldr /bootmgr` to the /boot/grub/grub.cfg file under the menu entry for Windows 10 and after `chainloader +1`. However, i know that the grub.cfg file is created with templates and if I accidentally run `update-grub` my changes will be gone.

So my question is how do I make this change permanent. I found out that there is a file in /etc/grub.d/40_custom that inserts custom menu entries to the grub.cfg file every time `update-grub` runs but I can not figure out how exactly to create the proper menu entry. Simply copy/pasting the menu entry from the grub.cfg produces syntax errors. So if someone could translate the grub.cfg code pasted here under into what must go in 40_custom I would be very grateful.

`menuentry 'Windows 10 (loader) (on /dev/sdg1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-585$
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ntfs
        set root='hd6,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd6,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd6,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ah$
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 585EDFF85EDFCD3E
        fi
        parttool ${root} hidden-
        drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
        chainloader +1
        ntldr /bootmgr
}`

Comment: I do not understand how you got it to work editing in first place. The ntldr command is an alternative or replacement of chainloader. Or once you run the chainloader command you will not get to the ntldr command. Is drive hd6 or sdg? Sdg implies hd7, but unless you have drives plugged into SATA ports in order and no skips of ports, drive number can change. When I first configured system and skipped a port, my flash drive became sdb, and every other drive moved up one.

Comment: I found a post here on AskUbuntu and the guy suggested that i add ntldr after chainloader. So I did that and it worked. I don't know how. Its hd6 not sdg.

Comment: Have you then tried with one or the other, but not both?

Comment: I just tried with only ntldr and it works, only chainloader it does not, and with both chainloader and ntldr it does work as long as ntldr comes after the chainloader.